# How to test Google Play Multiplayer locally

Tags: android, multiplayer, google-play-services, google-play

I'm building a simple HTML5 game and I need to implement multiplayer **without** sharing the game on Google Play.

I'm using CocoonJS's [multiplayer api](http://ludei.github.io/atomic-plugins-docs/dist/doc/js/Cocoon.Multiplayer.GooglePlayGames.html).

How can I test Google Play Multiplayer locally? Do I really have to use websockets instead?